# AngularJS multiple Controllers with one Service: Asynchronous errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I am getting some asynchronous errors when executing a function on my controllers near-simultaneously. Each controller takes some data, and calls a method in a service for testing. The service returns a promise to the controller, manipulates the data passed in, then resolves the promise. The code outline for the service looks like so:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
//Service that our controller can access
app.service("testing", function($timeout, $q) {

  //Test function which takes a group, and returns a promise with the result
  this.Test = function(resultsLocation, testList, testFunction) {
    //promise we are returning
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var i = 0;

    //TestCallback loop
    TestCallBack = function(testList) {
        if (i < testList.length) {

            //perform a test on one item of the list
            testFunction(testList[i]).then(function() {
                //push result back to controller
                resultsLocation.push(testList[i].result);
                i++;

                //show result of that one item with scope update.
                //also looks visually pleasing to see test come in
                //one at a time
                $timeout(function() {
                    TestCallBack(testList);
                }, 100);
            });
        } else {
            //we are done. Resolve promise
            deferred.resolve("Done");
        }
    };

    //initiate loop
    TestCallBack(testList);

    //return promise
    return deferred.promise;
  };

});//testing Service
```

And then I have a few controllers that roughly look like this:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
//Peripheral
app.controller("peripheral#", function($scope, testing) {
    //self stuff
    $scope.Title = "Peripheral#";
    $scope.Summary = "";
    $scope.Results = new Array();

    //initial lin tests
    var DiagnosticsList = [
        //test1
        //test2
        //etc...
    ];

    //Tests routine
    $scope.Testing = function() {
        //reset results
        $scope.Results = new Array();
        $scope.Summary = "Testing...";

        //Do Tests
        testing.Test($scope.Results, DiagnosticsList, CustomTestingFunction1).then(
            function(result) {
                $scope.Summary = "Testing...";
            }, 
            function(error) {
                console.log("Error testing Peripheral1");
            }
        );
    };
});
```

"Testing" is called on a button press in the html. The problem is if controller1 calls "Testing", then controller2 calls "Testing", the promise will never be resolved in controller1. Worse still, some of the test results are pushed into controller 2's results.

Perhaps I'm missing something, but I could've sworn I read somewhere that a service will be it's own instance when a controller has it.

Anyways, here's a plunker demonstrating the behavior: https://plnkr.co/edit/fE5OD35LaXHWrhv0ohq2?p=preview

Pressing "Test" individually is fine, but if you press "Test" while the other controller is testing, you'll get odd behavior such as values being mixed up, and the first controller will never finish testing.

Comment: You have reentrance problem. When you call `Test` method of your service again before the first call promise resolved you have lost the reference to it. Remeber, that the services in the Angular are singleton.

Comment: Ok, that would explain it; I could've sworn I read somewhere the services were not singleton. Is a factory singleton as well? Is there a way to block execution of a singleton until it's finished? Or make the service act as if it's non-singleton? Sorry, I'm fairly new to angular and the idea of promises all-together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the service assigns a **global** variable, `TestCallBack`, to a reference to a local **anonymous** function. Instead declare it as a **named** function on the service function scope.

```
app.service("testing", function($timeout, $q) {

    //Test function which takes a group, and returns a promise with the result
    this.Test = function(resultsLocation, testList, testFunction) {
        //promise we are returning
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var i = 0;

        //TestCallback loop
    //DONT use global variable
    //TestCallBack = function(testList) {
    //INSTEAD use a named function
    function TestCallBack(testlist) {
            if (i < testList.length) {
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/NXYJwYUDM4LBngKFFPnq?p=preview)

---

> So just to clarify, declaring a function as a var puts it on the global scope even when declared inside a function?

The error was setting a value to an *undeclared* variable.

Assigning a value to an **undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a global variable** (it becomes a property of the global object) when the assignment is executed. The differences between declared and undeclared variables are:

1. Declared variables are constrained in the execution context in which they are declared. Undeclared variables are always global.
2. Declared variables are created before any code is executed. Undeclared variables do not exist until the code assigning to them is executed.
3. Declared variables are a non-configurable property of their execution context (function or global). Undeclared variables are configurable (e.g. can be deleted).

Because of these three differences, failure to declare variables will very likely lead to unexpected results. Thus **it is recommended to always declare variables, regardless of whether they are in a function or global scope.** And in ECMAScript 5 strict mode, assigning to an undeclared variable throws an error.<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)</sup>

In this case, when the `service.Test` function was called the second time, the global value `TestCallBack` was being replaced by a reference to the anonymous function in the second instantiation of the `service.Test` function. The anonymous `TestCallBack` function refers to a **closure<sup>[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)</sup>** of the `service.Test` function. A closure is a special kind of object that combines two things: a function, and the environment in which that function was created. So functions scheduled by the first instantiation were getting their `i` and `resultsLocation` switched to the [**closure**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) of the second instantiation of the `service.Test` function.

Comment: Thank you, this solves my problem. So just to clarify, declaring a function as a var puts it on the global scope even when declared inside a function?

Comment: There is no such thing as "declaring a function as a var". A `var` is a container for either a primitive or a reference. A var can be *assigned* to a function *reference*. And a var can be re-assigned to another reference (or primitive). The second call to the `service.test` function was *re-assigning* the global variable to a function reference that was using a different execution context and closure.